# data binding from jsp to controller spring mvc model has list as a atribute

Tags: json

I tried this way, but still the methods are not initialized and it gives null.

//model class set attribute

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

   private Set<PaymentMethod> methods;
```

//jsp form

```
      <input type="checkbox" name="customer.methods[0].type" value="CC">credit card<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="customer.methods[1].type" value="DC">debit card<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="customer.methods[2].type" value="PP">pay pal<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="customer.methods[3].type" value="BC">bank credit
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is quite hard to understand, but from what I can tell at first glance, you're trying to access a list as if it was an array which it isn't.

At least it should be `customer.getMethods().get(0).getType()` and so on.

The getters are there for clarity. Of course your entity has also to have getters and setters.

Comment: thanks for help,i use setters and getters,i want to bind data to customer object which has methods attribute,through spring controller using json from jsp page

Comment: Using what I said should work as long as customer is indeed an entity already in your jsp code